# ReactJS Semantic ui - Cannot type into form when value attribute exists

Tags: forms, reactjs, semantic-ui

I am following a ReactJS tutorial to set up a login form. Semantic ui is used and imported. The email and password are passed into the `value` attribute inside the form. When this happens, I cannot type anything into the form. As soon as I remove it, I can type information in but I assume it won't get passed into anywhere.

Cannot seem to find this issues anywhere else. Has anyone experienced this issue before?

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Form, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import Validator from 'validator';
import InlineError from '../messages/InlineError';



class LoginForm extends React.Component {
    state = {
        data: {
            email: "",
            password: ""
        },
        loading: false,
        errors: {}
    };

    //... is called spread
    onChange = e => this.setState({
        data: {...this.state.data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
    });

    //() means function takes no params
    onSubmit = () => {
        const errors = this.validate(this.state.data);
        this.setState({errors}); //if there are errors, display them
        if(Object.keys(errors).length === 0){
            this.props.submit(this.state.data);
        }
    };

    validate = (data) => {
        const errors = {};
        if(!Validator.isEmail(data.email))
            errors.email = "Invalid email";
        if(!data.password)
            errors.password = "Can't be blank";

        return errors;
    };

    render() {

        const { data, errors } = this.state; // import variables into html
        return (
            <div>
                <Form onSubmit={ this.onSubmit }>
                    <Form.Field error={!!errors.email}>
                        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email"
                               id="email"
                               placeholder="example@abc.com"
                               value={ data.email }
                               onChange={ this.onChange }/>
                        {errors.email && <InlineError text={errors.email}/>}
                    </Form.Field>
                    <Form.Field error={!!errors.email}>
                        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password"
                               id="password"
                               value={ data.password }
                               onChange={this.onChange}/>
                        {errors.password && <InlineError text={errors.password}/>}
                    </Form.Field>
                    <Button primary>Login</Button>
                </Form>
            </div>
        );

    }
}

LoginForm.propTypes = {
    submit: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};



export default LoginForm;
```

tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NO2DaxhoWHk&t=879s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
onChange = e => this.setState({
    data: {...this.state.data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
});
```

This function is setting the state to a variable that shares the name of your input field. Hence `e.target.name`. But your input fields do not have a name attribute.

You can fix that with:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Form, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import Validator from 'validator';
import InlineError from '../messages/InlineError';



class LoginForm extends React.Component {
    state = {
        data: {
            email: "",
            password: ""
        },
        loading: false,
        errors: {}
    };

    //... is called spread
    onChange = e => this.setState({
        data: {...this.state.data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
    });

    //() means function takes no params
    onSubmit = () => {
        const errors = this.validate(this.state.data);
        this.setState({errors}); //if there are errors, display them
        if(Object.keys(errors).length === 0){
            this.props.submit(this.state.data);
        }
    };

    validate = (data) => {
        const errors = {};
        if(!Validator.isEmail(data.email))
            errors.email = "Invalid email";
        if(!data.password)
            errors.password = "Can't be blank";

        return errors;
    };

    render() {

        const { data, errors } = this.state; // import variables into html
        return (
            <div>
                <Form onSubmit={ this.onSubmit }>
                    <Form.Field error={!!errors.email}>
                        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                        <input type="email"
                               id="email"
                               name="email"
                               placeholder="example@abc.com"
                               value={ data.email }
                               onChange={ this.onChange }/>
                        {errors.email && <InlineError text={errors.email}/>}
                    </Form.Field>
                    <Form.Field error={!!errors.email}>
                        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password"
                               id="password"
                               name="password"
                               value={ data.password }
                               onChange={this.onChange}/>
                        {errors.password && <InlineError text={errors.password}/>}
                    </Form.Field>
                    <Button primary>Login</Button>
                </Form>
            </div>
        );

    }
}

LoginForm.propTypes = {
    submit: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};



export default LoginForm;
```